Parsing strings as Date Ranges in TypeScript
Trying to refactor/optimise an existing method parsing the date range or a date:
const parseDateRange = (range: string): Date | null => {
if (!range?.length) {
            return null;
}
    // Handle "MM/YYYY" format
    if (/^\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(range)) {
            const [month, year] = range.split('/').map(Number);
            if (!isNaN(month) && !isNaN(year)) {
              return new Date(year, month - 1);
            }
          }
      
          // Handle "MM/DD/YYYY-MM/DD/YYYY" format
          const startDateString = range.slice(0, range.indexOf('-')).trim();
          const startDate = new Date(startDateString);
          if (!isNaN(startDate.getTime())) {
            return startDate;
     }
     return null;
};

I can probably use something like this type here:
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
string extends S ? string[] :
S extends '' ? [] :
S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, U]:
[S];

Would appreciate the recommendation how I would utilize this or similar to parse the delimited date range type here.

Hi I can probably use something like this type here: is this how you want your solution to be using this format?

Yes, just a general date format, don't care about invalid dates i.e. 02/31/2024

Oh awesome but there are libraries that do this such as 'date-fns'; is there a particular reason? Because I could see regex in play and somethings it might not get all cases.

Not using this lib currently. Is it suitable for this scenario - string to date conversion/validation? Thanks!

yeah, I like to think so even Moment.js and date-fns  and the likes, but i have provided you with an answer, since I am not sure the use case you want it for.

@D.lola Thanks for the help! So the types like this are useless for this?

Oh I am glad I could help, LOL! @your use of word "useless". well not quite I would say this more like reinventing the wheel, however, to be fair people write libraries independent of what is out there, solely because of vulnerabilities, so useless might be too harsh. ;)

@D.lola Relatively new to TS (.Net mainstream), trying to understand - I can create types like Split, but how to utilize them here or elsewhere, say if I need to parse strings? My question was more about that :-) If you could add smth to your answer would be great!

Oh I see, to help a bit think of types as something you want to define based on your requirement outside the data structure available , a classic example of using a type is type  Employee(it would contain different things such as salary (integer), employment date etc, you can also define your own type such as Logging data type. You might not necessarily use it in the context you have defined or provided, it could be considered an overkill. :)

@D.lola Thanks, very instructive! I can see why the type doesn't really add any value in this context.

I have modified it to suit your earlier idea...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am sure you can use different libraries for this such Moment.js and date-fns,
But I am just going to assume you need it for some specific cases(like you dont want an external lib). In that case you can go about this using this code I have provided below.
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> = string extends S
  ? string[]
  : S extends ""
  ? []
  : S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}`
  ? [T, U]
  : [S];

const parseDateRange = (range: string): string | null => {
  if (!range?.length) {
    return null;
  }

  // Handle "MM/YYYY" format
  const mmYYYYMatch = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/.exec(range);
  if (mmYYYYMatch) {
    const [_, month, year] = mmYYYYMatch.map(Number);
    if (month && year) {
      let new_date = new Date(year, month - 1);
      return new_date.toUTCString();
    }
  }

  // Handle "MM/DD/YYYY-MM/DD/YYYY" format
  const [start, end] = range.split("-").map((date) => date.trim());
  const startDate = new Date(start);
  const endDate = new Date(end);

  if (!isNaN(startDate.getTime())) {
    return startDate.toUTCString(); // Optionally, handle `endDate` if needed.
  }

  return null;
};

// Example usage
console.log(parseDateRange("08/2024")); // Expected output: Date object for August 2024
console.log(parseDateRange("08/12/2024-08/13/2024")); // Expected output: Date object for August 12, 2024
console.log(parseDateRange("Invalid input")); // Expected output: null

// convert from Z U T C to local time
const date = new Date("2024-08-12T00:00:00Z");
console.log(date.toLocaleString()); // Expected output: Local time for August 12, 2024


Results
Wed, 31 Jul 2024 23:00:00 GMT
Sun, 11 Aug 2024 23:00:00 GMT
null
8/12/2024, 1:00:00 AM

A request by OP on how to use Spilt type if I wanted to split a date
Here is an example :

type Split<S extends string, D extends string> = string extends S
  ? string[]
  : S extends ""
  ? []
  : S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}`
  ? [T, U]
  : [S];

// a type enforcer which expects a format of the date string
type DateParts = Split<'MM/DD/YYYY', '/'>; // the result would be something like this ['MM', 'DD', 'YYYY']

// func that uses the `Split` type to validate input structures.
function parseDateParts<T extends string>(formatDateToString: T): Split<T, '/'> {
  return formatDateToString.split('/') as Split<T, '/'>;
}

// how ts would infer from it
const parts = parseDateParts('08/12/2024'); // TypeScript infers ['08', '12', '2024']

Alternatively
You can use it in this way

// the spilt type provided
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> = string extends S
  ? string[]
  : S extends ""
  ? []
  : S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}`
  ? [T, ...Split<U, D>]
  : [S];

// trying to mimic date formats ... 
type MMYYYY = `${number}/${number}`;

//  MM/DD/YYYY-MM/DD/YYYY format
type DateRange = `${number}/${number}/${number}-${number}/${number}/${number}`;

// refactor func to use utility types
const parseDateRange = (range: string): Date | null => {
  if (!range?.length) {
    return null;
  }

  // match the MM/YYYY format
  if (/^\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(range)) {
    // Use Split to ensure correct type handling
    const [month, year] = range.split("/") as Split<MMYYYY, "/">;
    const date = new Date(Number(year), Number(month) - 1);
    return isNaN(date.getTime()) ? null : date;
  }
  return null;
};

